# Oracle UTL_FILE.fremove (or frename) permission denied

Tags: plsql, permissions, oracle12c, utl-file

We have a oracle 12.1.0.2 installation on Linux, we have a procedure that read files from a folder, process data and writes file to another folder, and we have all permission required **on the folder**, so it works up to this point.
The problem arise when we try to remove the source file from the starting folder, because the database user has all the the rights on the folder but not on the specific file! Users and suppliers can upload file in this folder via ftp and we couldn't find way to replicate folder permission, I attach a couple of screenshots, please help.

Oracle error is ORA-29283: Invalid file operation
[Folder Rights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbpry.jpg)

[File Rights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMFLC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

*During creation of the files, the permission `-rwxr-xr-x` might be granted by issuing :*

`$ chmod 755 test_ftp.xlsx` or `$ chmod a+x test_ftp.xlsx` for related file to be able to be deleted.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not feasible to run chmod after every user operation.

Comment: @Federico ok, maybe. Did you try in such a way?

Comment: At the moment we have only two users uploading so we set up their Winscp to upload files with the permission needed, it's not exactly the perfect solution but at least it's working.